# Set web part personalizable property from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-parts

I have defined a personalizable property on a web part and I would like to modify its value from JavaScript. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use AJAX to send a message to the server. There's no way to set it from JavaScript without going to the server.

The AJAX could be as simple as a [PageMethod call](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx) though.